# Proving a triple angle formula for sine

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to prove that $\sin(3\alpha) = 3\sin(\alpha) - 4\sin^2(\alpha)$.

Using the angle sum rule, I've reached:

$\sin(3\alpha) = \sin(2\alpha)\cos(\alpha) + \cos(2\alpha)\sin(\alpha)$

Hence,

$\sin(3\alpha) = 2\sin(\alpha)\cos^2(\alpha) - \sin^3(\alpha) + \cos^2(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)$

How to proceed now ?

Comment: Use $sin^2(\alpha)+cos^2(\alpha)=1$ to get rid of the $cos^2$.

Answer (score 2):

You should have $\sin(3\alpha)=3\sin(\alpha)-4\sin^3(\alpha).$ You've determined that $$\sin(3\alpha)=2\sin(\alpha)\cos^2(\alpha)-\sin^3(\alpha)+\cos^2(\alpha)\sin(\alpha),$$ so gathering like terms gets us $$\sin(3\alpha)=3\sin(\alpha)\cos^2(\alpha)-\sin^3(\alpha).$$ Finally, the (Pythagorean) identity $\cos^2(\alpha)=1-\sin^2(\alpha)$ gets us where we need to be.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

$$\sin(3\alpha) \stackrel{!}{=} 3\sin(\alpha) - 4\sin^3(\alpha)$$

---

Hence $$\cos^2(\alpha)=1-\sin^2(\alpha)$$
You have

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\sin(3\alpha) &=& 2\sin(\alpha)\cos^2(\alpha) - \sin^3(\alpha) + \cos^2(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)\\
&=& 2\sin(\alpha)\left(1-\sin^2(\alpha)\right) - \sin^3(\alpha) + \left(1-\sin^2(\alpha)\right)\sin(\alpha)\\
&=& 3\sin(\alpha) - 4\sin^3(\alpha)
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You might want proceed as follows:

$$\sin(2\alpha + \alpha) = \sin 2\alpha \, \cos{\alpha} + \cos 2\alpha \, \sin \alpha,$$

then apply that $\sin 2\alpha = 2 \sin\alpha \cos\alpha$ and $\cos2\alpha = (1-2 \sin^2 \alpha)$ to get:

$$ \sin(2\alpha+\alpha)= 2\sin\alpha \, (1-\sin^2\alpha) + (1-2\sin^2\alpha) \sin\alpha,$$

where I have used the fundamental trigonometric identity. Further simplifcation leads you to the result.

Cheers!